# How to make UILocalNotification not repeat in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm a newbie in swift language. I am using UILocalNotification to make a local notification. In Objective-C, I can sent repeatInterval to not repeat by assigning it to 0.

```
UILocalNotification* alarm      = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
alarm.repeatInterval    = 0;
```

But when I assign 0 to repeatInterval in Swift I got an error.

```
let alarm : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
alarm.repeatInterval = 0
```

[image]

If you have any idea to fix it, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You could likely set it to zero like this:

```
alarm.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 0)
```

This way you are properly casting the value.